# GStreamer android tutorials are not working

Tags: android, media-player, media, gstreamer

I configured gstreamer on android. There are inbuilt tutorials in the gst-sdk folder in the gstreamer sdk kit. But somehow am not able to build them. Tutorial 1 works out fine. But the eclipse gets hanged when i build the other four tutorials. Does anyone have any idea regarding that? Basically i want to generate a media player in eclipse using gstreamer.

Comment: can you please explain more **But the eclipse gets hanged** I am not sure what does that mean, do you have build error?

Comment: I mean to say that when i confirm the generation of .so file (add native support) to my application, eclipse stops responding. Then i have to compulsorily force close the eclipse window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you try the followings:

1. First, add "ifdef BUILD_PROJECT" and "endif" at the beginning and end of the Android.mk in the JNI folder.
2. Next, append an option to the build command: "ndk-build BUILD_PROJECT=1" ([Properties] -> [C/C++ Build] -> [Build command])

I guess this problem is in synchronization of threads or processes associated with CDT... maybe.
At least, I could build the tutorial 2-5 after the above settings (and the other settings are default) with no problems.

Good luck !

Comment: Checking it out.. will get back to you asap :)

Answer (score -1):

are you using eclipse inside virtual machine?
I got the similar problems when I used eclipse inside oracle virtualbox.
once I killed the eclipse process, it still hangs when i open it next time.
I removed the Preference -> Builders -> Scanner Configuration Builder.  and It helps fixing the problem.
eclipse still hangs sometime when I open any project got native support.  I just remove jni (e.g. changing name).  then open eclipse, wait until it finishes initailization.  then move jni directory back, refresh the project.  it works for me.  sorry, I don't know what cause this.  but it did happened more often inside virtual machine than on the real machine.

Comment: Hey, thanks emily. But it didnt work for me :( Eclipse.exe still stops responding once i add native support to any tutorial. Any other solution is welcomed :)